# Why are all the partitions not assinged to the single KafkaConsumer that is running?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to read the last 3 records from the topic "input_topic".
I am using only a single consumer.
But it is consuming record from only one partition.

When I manually assigned other partitions, an error comes "You can only check the position for partitions assigned to this consumer."
But I am using a single consumer.
I am not able to understand the issue.
Please help me out if possible.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,"4");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");

KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
String topic = "input_topic";
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
TopicPartition topicPartition1 = new TopicPartition(topic, 1);    
TopicPartition topicPartition2 = new TopicPartition(topic, 2);
List<TopicPartition> topics = Arrays.asList(topicPartition1,topicPartition,topicPartition2);
while (true) {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  consumer.assign(topics);
  consumer.seekToEnd(topics);

  long current = consumer.position(topicPartition);
  consumer.seek(topicPartition, current-3);
  ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
  System.out.println("-------------------------------------------> "+ records.count());
  System.out.println("-------------------------------------------> "+ LocalDateTime.now());
  for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
    System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
    System.out.println("_________________________" + record.partition());
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste a full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Why are you calling assign method inside while loop? It seems it should have done once.

Answer (score 1):

My guess ... other than what Hatice said about `assign` which should be made outside of the loop just one time, I see this from your code.
You seek the position at the end of all topic partitions but then you seek on the offset for the last 3 records just for the topic partition 0.
At that point, the poll is able to consume just only those 3 records from topic partition 0 and not from other partitions because your position on them is at end (of course, it's true if you are not sending more messages to those partitions as well).